# problem in setContentView() when I am running the application, it does not work

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.uberapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyConfig;
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                                       .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Arkhip_font.ttf")
                                    .addCustomStyle(AppCompatTextView.class,android.R.attr.textViewStyle)
                                     .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                                        .build());
        setContentView(R.activity_main);


    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, you NEED an App class and init the Calligraphy inside it. You cant init it inside MainActivity!

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

this is proper `layout` declaration (`R.layout` prefix)

Comment: i fixed it but the same problem

Comment: Post your 'Caused by' stack trace. Also in your question, you used R.activity_main. Check if that's a typo or not.

Comment: Do you have Instagram sent you pictures of the problem

Comment: Don't send me any pics. Just use the edit link under ur question to add snippets of the stack trace.

Comment: I used but the same problem

Comment: not `R.activity_main`, use `R.layout.activity_main` - note `layout` in the middle... just use copy/paste... or use autosuggesting, put cursor after any dot (e.g after `R.`) and press ctrl + space